# how to stop defaulting of checkbox to checked on load of grid in extjs 4.0

Tags: extjs

I have a checkcolumn in declared in a grid like this

```
{
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            id: 'app',
            text: '<b>Approve</b>',
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'approveInd',
            menuDisabled : true
}
```

and my model is

```
{
        name : 'approveInd'
        type: 'bool'
    },
```

if i remove the type : bool in my model and load the grid, the checkcolumn is coming is checked by default. 
my basic requirement is to send this checkcolumn value as string to db. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep `type:'bool'`, afterall that is the proper type. If the server needs a string representing boolean values ('OFF', 'ON', or whatever), you can implement [`serialize`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-serialize) function that would convert boolean (internal) value to string that can be understood by the server.